Unable get Ocelot to use Serilog for its logging
I am developing an asp.net gateway application on top of Ocelot. I am using Serilog as a logger.
Problem: Ocelot package itself is not writing to this logfile, for example, bad requests etc, even though lot of logging calls sprinkled throughout Ocelot.
Whatever I myself am logging, using Log.Information etc, is being logged.
Here is my main program in .NET 8 (simplified):
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
configuration.AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{env}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
var services = builder.Services;
...
services.AddOcelot();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
Log.Information("Ocelot gateway app starting up"); //this is being logged correctly


var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseOcelot().Wait();
app.Run();

Here is my appsettings.file
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [  "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": { "path": "C:\\temp\\ocelot\\logs-staging.txt" }
    }
  ]
}

